# Need Help Connecting Arduino to PC via RS485 with Max485 breakout board

Tags: arduino, rs485, modbus

I am currently attempting to connect an arduino to a PC via the RS485 communication protocol using a max485 to convert the RS485 to serial. It does not however appear to be receiving any data at all. The circuit I am using is this;
[image: Circuit used]

And the code is;

```cpp
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>   // Using software serial library
    
    #define SSerialRX        10   // Serial Receive pin  (RO)
    #define SSerialTX        11   // Serial Transmit pin (DI)
    
    #define SSerialTxControl 3    // RS485 Direction control
    //(DE & RE) pin to digital pin 3
    
    #define RS485Transmit    HIGH // to open direction of MAX485 module
    #define RS485Receive     LOW  // to close direction of MAX485 module
    
    #define Pin13LED         13   // Built in LED to indicate command has recieved
    
    SoftwareSerial RS485Serial(SSerialRX, SSerialTX); // initialize RX and TX
    
    char x;                         // Containing data recieved
    
    void setup() {
      pinMode(Pin13LED, OUTPUT);                    // Pin13LED as OUTPUT
      pinMode(SSerialTxControl, OUTPUT);            // SSerialTxControl as OUTPUT
      digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive); // initial set SSerialTxControl are closed
      RS485Serial.begin(9600);                      // RS485Serial baudrate 9600
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    
    void loop() {
    
      if (RS485Serial.available()) { // Checking Serial available 
        x = RS485Serial.read();         // Serial read by saving in x variable
        Serial.println(x);
        if (x == '1') { //'3'){             // Checking condition, if 1 and 2 for NANO 1, 3 and 4 for NANO 2
          digitalWrite(Pin13LED, HIGH);
        }
        else if (x == '2') { //'4'){
          digitalWrite(Pin13LED, LOW);
        }
      } 
      else {
        Serial.println("No Data");
      }
    }
```

This is the example "Blink" sketch for MuchammadSobrun's `PC-to-Arduino-by-MAX485-Module` library which seems that it should do exactly what I need - which is first to communicate with the arduino via modbus protocol and then after that to treat the arduino as a modbus device with coils etc. However it doesn't seem data is being recieved. I have added the line `Serial.println(x)` to print the incoming Rs485 serial data to the hardware serial port whenever data is recieved via rs485, however nothing is being shown on the arduino serial monitor. I am using the modbus poll software as well as Qmodbus to send modbus instructions to the device such as `Read Holding Registers`: `01 03 00 00 00 01`, however sending these yields no result. Please help, I have lost many nights of sleep over this.

Comment: Firstly, RS485 is not a protocol, Modbus is. What tests have you performed? Swap A and B? Have the arduino send short messages. Use your PC sound card as an oscilloscope to see what is happening. For all we know there could be multiple problems, so you need to work logically to verify each step.

Comment: How do you know that "Qmodbus" or whatever it is has correctly opened your PC serial port and actually transmitting data? You have no info to know what USB RS485 module that is and what kind of serial port setup it needs to control the RS485 tranveiver into transmit mode. Use a standard terminal first. Also if Arduino MCU is running at 3.3V, the 5V data from RS485 module might have fried it already. Oh and for some reason people leave RS485 bus grounds floating, and floating nodes don't communicate well with others.

Comment: One of the basic things you must do with RS485 is to terminate it. You need a termination resistor at both physical ends, something in the 120-140 ohm range. Without the termination it probably will not work.

Comment: @gil. Termination isn’t necessarily required. In some instances adding termination will stop the bus working. The RS485 spec says there should be a minimum of 200mV on the bus to ensure an idle condition. If you add termination then the bias resistors also need to be correctly sized.
For CAN it is not optional.

Comment: Here is an excellent article by TI. I always put them in, they can be removed if wanted. I typically do it with a pair of jumper pins. Not knowing the system and from past experience problems generally arise from termination problems or lack thereof.